# ScalaTest - how to use forEvery without printing the entire collection?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala-2.11

Is there any way to use ScalaTest's forEvery inspector without having it print the entire collection on each test failure? The collection I'm trying to run the test on is pretty large (over a thousand elements) and I'm not really that interested in seeing its contents in test logs, especially if the offending line of text is already printed in the collected error messages. Having six tests using that collection doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution I have found is really ugly and hackish. The way forEvery (and other Inspectors too, I suspect) work is that they try to get your collection's iterator if they can, both to run the tests and to print out your collection. My solution passes the correct iterator only on the first run, and if the inspector tries to grab the iterator again (which it does only to print the collection out) it gets Seq.empty.iterator. The best thing which can be said about this code is that it works:

```
def forEvery[E](xs: TraversableOnce[E])(fun: E => Unit): Unit = {
  class SilentSeq[E](list: TraversableOnce[E]) extends Seq[E] {
    var silent: Boolean = false
    def length = 0
    def apply(i: Int) = list.toIterator.next()
    def iterator = {
      if (silent)
        Seq.empty.iterator
      else {
        silent = true
        list.toIterator
      }
    }
  }

  Inspectors.forEvery[E, Seq](new SilentSeq(xs))(fun)
}
```

The inspector doesn't use either length or apply, so whatever I put there is irrelevant, as long as it has the correct type. Extending Seq is just about the easiest way I have found to pretend to be a GenTraversable (which is needed to have my own class' iterator used). I would be happy to find any solution that is better than this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `forAll` instead of `forEvery`.

From [docs](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.1/index.html#org.scalatest.Inspectors):

- `forAll` - succeeds if the assertion holds true for every element
- `forEvery` - same as forAll, but lists all failing elements if it fails (whereas `forAll` just reports the first failing element)

Comment: Listing all failing elements is exactly what I want, otherwise a simple foreach would suffice. What I don't want is having the entire collection printed below the elements that failed the test.

Comment: There currently isn't a way to prevent that. It is at the end so you can "ignore" it if you don't care. Can you explain how it is hard to ignore? Is it the need to scroll through it in the standard out reporter output?

Comment: As I said, the collection I'm running the tests with is huge. It's over a thousand elements, possibly close to 2k. That's multiple screens of text I don't care about, and that is only if one of tests fails. Things get only worse if there's more than one failure. I've already found an ugly solution, and sadly it seems like there is no reasonable way to filter the text out. I'm going to post it in a few hours when I have access to my laptop.